# Prevent AWS load balancer serving on IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, ip-address, amazon-elb, host-headers

I've configured a Amazon Webservices Load Balancer for my site.

It's all good the domain name resolves to the IP address of the Load Balancer Endpoint, and on the internal LAN it communicates with my two front end webservers.

I've noticed in webmaster tools that Google has picked up the IP of the load balancer and is serving the site up on the IP address as well as when the host name is used.

E.g.  54.76.x.x

If it were IIS I could use the host-header setting to block it serving up on the IP as well but there appears to be no control over this in the AWS admin panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in your appserver.  The AWS load balancer is pretty dumb; it doesn't do much of anything other than take requests and forward them.  Configure your appserver to respond "appropriately" (404, 403, whatever) to requests that don't have an appropriate `Host` header, and Google will get the message pretty quick.

Comment: The AWS load balancer will send the Host-Header through?  Haha its me that being dumb.  I check..

Comment: For some reason I thought it would strip the header and just pull on whatever port was there.  Yes setting the host headers in IIS on both machines - actually I am using port 83 for this particular site locked it down.